# How to install Linux under non-encrypted partition when using Bitlocker

Tags: multi-boot, bitlocker

I have three partitions: a boot partition, a general partition with Windows installed and BitLocker active and a third partion, unencrypted.

Can I install Linux without reinstalling Windows from this setup? Or will this corrupt the boot partition in a way that BitLocker can no longer be used (and I consequently lose access to the main partition)?

Answer (score 0):

You install linux in this situation , just make sure that you install the grub boot loader onto the unencrypted partition. Also keep in mind that you can only access your bitlocker drive from within windows.

Comment: My fear is whether this can possibly corrupt the (unencrypted) boot partition so the windows partition is no longer available.

Comment: Didn't work; just butchered my boot partition, like I expected. I installed grub onto it, and when I select the Vista bootloader it just returns to the GRUB screen. Restoring the partition from backup now and hoping it'll work...

Comment: OK I dd'ed the partition back... I guess now the question is how to install grub so I can boot again to linux and still be able to boot to windows.

Comment: I'm gonna give this a try: http://blogs.technet.com/b/voy/archive/2006/10/13/building-a-dual-boot-system-with-windows-vista-bitlocker-protection-with-tpm-support.aspx

Comment: As I said you should have installed grub onto the un-encrypted partition not onto the current boot partition.If you install it on a partition other than the current boot one linux will pick up that windows is installed already. Also all this is based on your distro being ubuntu ,since i havent tested it on other distros

Comment: Fair enough, but both "unencrypted partition is ambiguous" since with bitlocker the boot partition is unencrypted. I'm now using the windows bootloader as described in the blog post, but unfortunately I can only start linux through the grub command line, which is where it leaves me...